# Reactstrap does not render h-100 properly

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have following code. to render a layout in React using reactstrap.
I believe I have given the correct style to provide the 100% height, but for some reason unknown, the Row component (height: 527px) will not grow it's height to the size of Container component (height: 899px).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { TopMenu } from './TopMenu';
import { SideMenu } from './SideMenu';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import './Layout.css';

export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <Container fluid className="min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column p-0">
        <TopMenu />
        <Container className="flex-grow-1 pt-3 test">
          <Row className="h-100 test2">
            <Col md="2">
              <SideMenu />
            </Col>
            <Col md="10">
              {this.props.children}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Footer />    
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I have given following CSS to confirm that the container height is grown.

```
:root {
  --theme-color: #14279B;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;
}
#root {
  height: 100%;
}
.test {
  background-color:#ffff00
}
.test2 {
  background-color:#ff00ff
}
```

What should I do to get my Row component to grow as the size of my Container component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who find this question in the future, I have resolved this issue by changing the min-vh-100 to vh-100 for the container component. I am still puzzled on why the min vh and just vh may differ the output though.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { TopMenu } from './TopMenu';
import { SideMenu } from './SideMenu';
import { Footer } from './Footer';
import './Layout.css';

export class Layout extends Component {
  static displayName = Layout.name;

  render () {
    return (
      <Container fluid className="vh-100 d-flex flex-column p-0">
        <TopMenu />
        <Container className="flex-grow-1 pt-3 test">
          <Row className="h-100 test2">
            <Col md="2">
              <SideMenu />
            </Col>
            <Col md="10">
              {this.props.children}
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <Footer />    
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```